# dotnet .OleDbException "The connection for viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost"

Tags: c#, excel

I am reading data from excel thru olddb, and then to keep into a data table, and to save in sqlserver db, I didn successfully in local, but same code is throwing an exception in webserver as "The connection for viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost" thru System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException. Data is read once from excel sheet successfully but while reading again its raising error, although i closed connection with the following code.

```
    if (objConn != null)
        {
            objConn.Close();
            objConn.Dispose();
        }
        if (dt != null)
        {
            dt.Dispose();
        }
```

and second time i am reading the data from excel with this code follows:

```
                string constr1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("images\\" + "TempFolder\\" + filename) + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";

                System.Data.DataTable dtUpload = new System.Data.DataTable();

                OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(constr1);
                //[designation],
                //string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + "[" + sb + "]";

                string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + "[" + sb + "]";

                oledbConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, oledbConn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);
```

Its showing the exception thru last line of code.

Comment: "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."